# Как извлечь в массив все элементы Html под определенным Div?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть некоторый элемент `DIV`. А в нем подэлементы, а под элементами еще подэлементы. Вопрос таков: как мне извлечь все-все элементы под одним элементом, допустим

```
<div id='parentElem'>
<!-- много-много элементов и подэлементов и под-под-под-подэлементов -->
</div>
```

P.S. **Без** применения библиотек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбираем из документа элемент с данным id, сохраняем в переменной, а потом делаем с ним и его потомками что хотим согласно Объектной Модели Документа (DOM) в JS.

[DOM в JS](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom)

[Конкретно - так](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom/search#poluchit-vseh-potomkov)

Answer (score 2):

если с использованием jquery

```
var mass = [];
$('#parentElem .filter-options').each(function(index)
{
  mass.push(this);
}
```

где **.filter-options** это твои под элементы, соовтетветнно если хочешь подподэлементы то указываешь класс элементов внутри **filter-options** 
без jquery как-то так

```
var mass  = document.getElementById('parentElem').getElementsByClassName('filter-options');
```

Comment: назвал так просто потому что у самого только что был похожий код в проекте открыт , поэтому просто копипастнул, слово filter сокрального смысла не имеет =)

Comment: И это хорошо. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: долго печатал, опередили)))

Answer (score 0):

[.childNodes](http://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=ru&cp=11&gs_id=d&xhr=t&q=.childNodes&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&newwindow=1&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=.childNodes&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=dfb6e20195086b3&ion=1&biw=1680&bih=965) + [рекурсия](http://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#pq=.childnodes&hl=ru&cp=4&gs_id=e&xhr=t&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&newwindow=1&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=dfb6e20195086b3&biw=1680&bih=965&ion=1)

Comment: абсолютно солидарен, че это сегодня всех на рекурсию потянуло? :D

Comment: кстати да))

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать это, указываете элемент внутри которого желаете получить элементы и при обходе каждого получаете данные

```
    var form = document.getElementById('root_element_on_form');

    for(var i = 0; i < form.childNodes.length; i++){
        console.log('SELECTED:'+form.childNodes[i].getAttribute("data-select"));
    }
```

Думаю это как альтернатива , без Jquery

Comment: jquery обходит по элементам, а не нодам

Comment: Grundy  -  но ведь будет работать и получить все элементы , и делать с ними что угодно. Хоть в массив их хоть куда

Comment: На самом деле не все, не получит вложенные элементы. Кроме того вернет текстовые ноды, которые обычно не рассчитывают получать